# Prime zeta definition, multiplication by zero

Tags: number-theory, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Wikipedia has a page about the prime zeta function which is defined as follows:

$$P(s)=\sum_{p\;\text{prime}} \frac1{p^s}$$

I entered this additional definition:

Define a sequence:
$$a_n=\prod_{d\mid n} \frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)},$$
where zeros are not included in the multiplication and $a_1=1$ then:
$$P(s)=\log\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}.$$
Is it a problem that this later definition does not include the zeros in the multiplication?

Comment: What is $\Lambda(n/d)$? Is it the Von Mangoldt function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function)? Then that should be explained both here and at Wikipedia.

Comment: I might have made a mistake but what I had in mind was the Mangoldt function applied to the divisors of n. In oeis notation which I understand better I would have said: For row>1: a(n)^-1 = row products of A100995(A126988).

Comment: @joriki Ok, nothing new then. But I don't think this is mentioned in the oeis.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing new"? I only linked to the Von Mangoldt function to make what you wrote intelligible to someone who doesn't know this symbol (like I didn't), not to imply that there is nothing new in what you wrote. As you may be aware, it's Wikipedia policy that you shouldn't put anything new in there (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:OR). I personally don't think this should apply too rigorously to mathematics, since proofs can be checked without secondary sources. But what you wrote doesn't form a natural part of the article. I think you should either flesh it out or delete it.

Comment: It's an interesting relationship, by the way. But why don't you write $d$ instead of $n/d$?

Comment: I guess you are right about the n/d, I should have written only d. I have had problems with this notation because I always think of row index divided by column index when I see it.

Comment: Your definition of $a_n$ seems rather complicated, all the more so since you have to exclude the zeroes and the Von Mangoldt function isn't terribly well-known -- wouldn't it be more straightforward to just say that $a_n$ contains a factor $1/k!$ for each maximal prime power $p^k$ in its factorization? (Or equivalently a factor $1/k$ for each prime power $p^k$ that divides it.)

Comment: Also, I wouldn't call what you wrote an "additional definition" of $P$ -- the actual definition is clearly more direct and simple; what you wrote is a relationship involving $P$, not something one would use to define $P$.

Comment: Mats, I edited the wikipedia page to include Joriki's suggested simplification.  I would like to see you add a justification or citation for this identity, otherwise it might be deleted as original research (it might be anyway, but it would be good to add some supporting information).  Cheers.

Comment: If you add a new definition to Wikipedia, please have a reference for it, preferably in the form of a published article.